# Extending ArrayList causes missing properties in Jersey, Java

Tags: java, jersey

I am creating a rest service with a collection resource of cars,
In the code I am setting the ID of the collection for later use,
However when I return a response of CarResources the ID is missing.
Also the IDE does not seem to 'see' this property

Code:

```
public class CarResources extends ArrayList<CarResource> {

  private String id;

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }


  public CarResources (String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
```

Response:

```
[
//Missing in the response is an id property of the entire List
  {
    "CarResource": {
      "id": "TOYOTA_CAMERI",
      "name": "Toyota",
      "carType": "GAS"
      }
   },
     {
    "CarResource": {
      "id": "HONDA_TYPE_R",
      "name": "HONDA",
      "carType": "GAS"
      }
   }


]
```

Comment: Dont extend ArrayList. Create a custom class that  has the List as field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest thing to do is **not** extend `ArrayList` and just have the list as a member of your custom object, it wills serialize without any additional effort then. Inheritance in this case is not the correct solution, composition is.

If you insist on extending `ArrayList` you need to annotate your new instance member with `@JsonProperty` and/or write a custom `JsonSerializer<CarResources>`  and annotate the class with `@JsonSerialize` to use the new custom serializer because the default `ArrayList` serializer is being used otherwise.

Comment: Thanks I have added the protected ArrayList<E> data; to our BaseCollection resource and it solved it.

Comment: @Nir Instead of adding thank's comment consider to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) answer checking the green check next to answer